# Python 2.6.4 - method name is not defined

Tags: python

Running a python script named `automator.py` from the command line using powershell on windows 7.

`python .\automator.py`

`automator.py` file looks like this....

```
import os

ipAddressFile = os.path.join("DCM_Info", "ip_address")
ipAddresses = getIpAddresses()

for ip in ipAddresses:
    print str(ip)
    cmd = "python run.py " + ip  + " get_transrator_settings"
    os.system(cmd)


def getIpAddresses():
    f = open(ipAddressFile, 'r')
    return f.readlines()
```

Why am I getting an error that the name of the method is undefined?

`NameError: name 'getIpAddresses' is not defined`

I'm used to C#/Java where you have a main method that starts the program and classes that have constructors. Do I need to have a constructor or a class? Is that necessary?

Comment: in C# or Java the flow of execution is  `compile methods -> start main method > .... > finish` so once the `main` has started all the definitions have already run, however in python it is just `start file > ... > finish` so the function is only defined at (and then after) the `def` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the function definition to be *before* the first time it is used. It can be easy to forget about this, since languages like JavaScript allow functions to be declared after they're called.